# Chomsky Normal Form correctness

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, chomsky-normal-form

I have these productions:

```
S->aSb
S-> eps      (eps=empty string)
```

I should apply the Chomsky Normal Form

My reasoning:

1) eliminate the eps rules
Given:

```
S->aSb
S-> eps
```

I get:

```
S->ab

S->aSb
```

2) eliminate the unit rules

There are none

3) remove useless symbols

I get:

```
S->ab
```

So, the given grammar after applying CNF (Chomsky Normal Form) becomes:

```
S->ab
```

Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is not quite the same.  Notice that the empty string is no longer part of your language, nor are the strings aabb, aaabbb, etc.

Chec the step where you eliminate useless rules.  Is that second rule really useless?

Also, are you sure you can eliminate the epsilon production?

Comment: that's correct..you're right.Applying the CNF implies removing the eps productions..but here I only have one eps rule...I'm confused

Comment: OK the rule S->eps cannot be excluded because S is the start symbol..so Everything I did was wrong..

Comment: @josè: Actually, you dont't have to remove all the eps productions. Grammar in CNF can contain rule S -> \epsilon, where S is the initial terminal and it mustn't not occur on right side of any production rule.

Comment: symbol..so Everything I did was wrong..I suppse everything remains unchanged ..Am I right? So the final result is S->aSb and S->eps but that is something different from having A->a A->BC as the CNF specifications suggest